# How can I send an alert when this specific link is loaded on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a website for a small game I'm working on. And the website's index page can be found [here](https://tfojofficialwebsite.glitch.me/index.html). The videos page doesn't work properly on mobile, and I want to make an alert show up when the videos page is loaded.

Here's what I had:

```
window.onload = function () {
      if (document.url == "https://tfojofficialwebsite.glitch.me/videos.html") {
    if (
      navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
    ) {
      console.log("true");
      alert("This page may not work properly on your device.");
    } else {
      console.log("false");
    }
  }
};
```

And what I was expecting was an alert when the page is loaded on mobile, but it doesn't do anything, mobile or not. What did I mess up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that your code is not functioning properly. The issue seems to be with the use of

```js
document.url
```

This property is undefined, but you can achieve the desired result by using

```
if (window.location.href == "https://tfojofficialwebsite.glitch.me/videos.html")
```

This is a simple change, and it should resolve the problem with your code.